# AddIn Suggestions for Visual Studio 6 / Visual Basic 6 Code Nagivigation & Exploring

Tags: vb6, navigation

I am looking for good Visual Studio 6 Addins for code navigation and exploring.

For instance, I want to have the functionality of showing in- and outcoming calls of methods like Resharper already has.

Furthermore I am looking for a simpler code navigation.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [MZ-Tools 3.0](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx) for Visual Basic 6.0 : I've found it quite helpful in the past

Comment: +1 MZTools is essential! It can list callers to methods, and it has an improved search dialog. BTW Took the liberty of editing your answer and correcting your typo